# Guice servlet DSL, filter all but one URL

Tags: java, servlets, guice

I want to filter all requests to my web application through my "SecurityFilter" which checks that a session variable "authToken" is valid.  The problem is that in order to get this token you need to hit the "AuthServlet" which is at /auth.

I need to filter all servlets except the /auth servlet with my "SecurityFilter".  How can I do this via guice-servlet?

I thought of trying to no avail...

```
filterRegex("!((.)*auth(.)*)").through(PortSecurityFilter.class);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^((?!/authorize).)*$` worked.